# JS array string patch name to array(object)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, parsing, converters

i have trouble with js array.
I have patch name(string)  look like ( "user.joey.friends.0.franc" ) and i need to "compress" to look like this:

```
console.log( parseArray( "user.joey.friends.0.franc" ) );
//Object {
            user: {
                joey: {
                    friends: {
                        0: {
                            franc: 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Any ideas, how to do that ?

Comment: First: You are dealing with a JavaScript *object* -- with perhaps an array inside of it (depending on how you handle the '0').  Second -- what have you tried?   Your best solution is a recursive one -- take an object, see if your key `user` is there.  If not, add the key.  Then, pass that object and your next key `joey` down and walk through your string bit by bit.  You can use the `split` method on the string to break it apart.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but you can't reference a number in dot format like `variable.variable.0.variable` because it'll see it as a decimal. You have to use brackets as such `variable.variable[0].variable`

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. Are you saying you have an object with the structure you've quoted for `a`, and you're trying to look up the property defined by your string `"user.joey.friends.0.franc"`? If so, @Jeremy's on the right track, but it doesn't even have to be recursive, it's just a loop.

Comment: Thank for answers, but i have other problem, i have string name of array  ( "user.joey.friends.0.franc" ) and i need convert array name as object ( user:{ joey:{ .. } } )
@Jeremy J Starcher, thanks for idea, but is there more easy way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non recursive way to get you most of the way there.

```
function compress(str) {
    var split = str.split('.'), obj = {}, current = obj, i;

    for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        current[split[i]] =  {} ;
        current = current[split[i]];
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: If this worked for you I would appreciate you ticking the checkmark on this answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying you have an object with the structure you've quoted, and you're trying to look up the property defined by your string `"user.joey.friends.0.franc"`, that's a fairly straightforward loop: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/powev/1)

```
function findProperty(obj, path) {
    var steps = path.split(/\./);
    var step;
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < steps.length; ++n) {
        step = steps[n];
        if (!(step in obj)) {
            return undefined;
        }
        obj = obj[step];
    }
    return obj;
}

var a =  {
  user: {
    joey: {
      friends: {
        0: {
          franc: 1
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

console.log(findProperty(a, "user.joey.friends.0.franc")); // "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to create an object from a string, this solution is what I currently use until I find something better (I believe it based on a namespacing method from Yahoo):

```
function createObject() {
  var a = arguments, i, j, d, _this;
  var out = {};
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i = i + 1) {
    d = a[i].split('.');
    out2 = out;
    for (j = 0; j < d.length; j = j + 1) {
      out2[d[j]] = out2[d[j]] || {};
      out2 = out2[d[j]];
    }
  }
  return out;
}

createObject('user.joey.friends.0.franc');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t92oaj/2/)