# Explode string into nested array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to convert these strings into a combined nested array:

```
array(
    'item1:item2:itemx',
    'item1:item2:itemy',
    'itemz'
)
```

To

```
array(
    'item1' => array(
        'item2' => array(
            'itemx' => array(),
            'itemy' => array(),
        )
    )
    'itemz' => array()
)
```

Is there a way to do this with explode/foreach loop?

Comment: Like in this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25510551/js-array-string-patch-name-to-arrayobject/25510794][1] ?

Comment: I would prefer a solution with PHP, and using arrays not objects.

Comment: are your strings in an array or are really named $string1, 2 etc. ?

Comment: @vlzvl There are nested in a larger array, I didn't include that part for simplicity. I'll make a quick edit...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question has been answered countless of times... please use search before posting a new question.

Anyway, here's one solution:

```
$strings = array(
                 'item1:item2:itemx',
                 'item1:item2:itemy',
                 'itemz'
                );

$nested_array = array();

foreach($strings as $item) {
    $temp = &$nested_array;

    foreach(explode(':', $item) as $key) {
        $temp = &$temp[$key];
    }

    $temp = array();
}

var_dump($nested_array);
```

Comment: I did indeed search before posting. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: There are similar questions yes but this one suited my needs exactly, thanks.