# Parsing associative array and exploding on an underscore

Tags: php

This seems simple, but has perplexed me. I need to get $env to look like $desired result.

I tried using explode and foreach loops in a multitude of ways but keep getting stuck.

```
$env = [
    ["mysql_user"=>"user var"],
    ["mysql_pass"=>"password var"],
    ["rabbit_list_one"=>"listone var"],
    ["rabbit_list_two"=>"listtwo var"],
    ["system_var_main_deep"=>"deep this"],
    ["system_var_main_that"=>"deep that"]
];

$desiredResult = [
    "mysql" => [
        "user" => "user var",
        "pass" => "password var"
    ],
    "rabbit" => [
        "list" => [
            "one" => "listone var",
            "two" => "listtwo var"
        ]
    ],
    "system" => [
        "var" => [
            "main" => [
                "deep" => "deep this",
                "that" => "deep that"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Comment: Yes simple is this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried foreach loops with explodes but each time either fail or limited to one or two loops. I feel their should be a clean way to do this that could handle a multitude of depths for environment variables. Stumped on what seems to be a simple thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536079/explode-string-into-nested-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the formatting on `$env`, because you're showing arrays inside of the `$env` array rather than just key/value pairs. Assuming your input is correct, and there are actually inner arrays, this should work:

```
$out = [];
foreach ($env as $piece) {
    foreach ($piece as $key => $value) {
        $key_full = explode('_', $key);
        $key_last = array_pop($key_full);
        $pointer = &$out;
        foreach ($key_full as $key_level) {
            if (!isset($pointer[$key_level])) {
                $pointer[$key_level] = [];
            }
            $pointer = &$pointer[$key_level];
        }
        $pointer[$key_last] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You have no idea how much this has helped me tonight. I hate to admit how long I have been coding and still get stuck on something as basic as this. I am forever grateful.

Comment: I'll be honest, it took me a few minutes to figure out. I'm not accustomed to using pointers (references) in PHP very often.

Comment: By the way, you were right about the arrays inside of env. That wasn't the case. My tests were incorrect. Either way though, your solution helped me get it fixed.

Comment: Yeah, it should be a simple matter of removing the first `foreach` and changing the variable names to match. By the way, since you're new, I figured I'd mention that accepting the best answer is standard procedure here (but feel free to wait to see if there's a better one!)

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to see this. Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Netrilix's answer, this was the final solution. This handled the situation where FOO_BAR_BAX and FOO_BAR were both set. We opted to always take the array over the string. Thank you all for all your help!

```
public function build() {
    $config = $_ENV;
    $out = [];
    foreach ($config as $key => $value) {
        $key_full = explode('_', $key);
        $key_last = strtolower(array_pop($key_full));
        $pointer  = &$out;

        foreach ($key_full as $key_level) {
            $key_level = strtolower($key_level);

            if (!isset($pointer[$key_level])) {
                $pointer[$key_level] = [];
            }

            $pointer = &$pointer[$key_level];
        }

        $pointer = !is_array($pointer) ? [] : $pointer;
        if (!isset($pointer[$key_last])) {
            $pointer[$key_last] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $out;
}
```