# PHP - "Undefined Index" notice not raised when referencing (&) an un-instantied element of an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, reference, undefined

I was looking at this code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536079/explode-string-into-nested-array):

```
$string = 'item1:item2:itemx';

$res = array();

$temp = &$nested_array;
foreach(explode(':', $string) as $key) {
    $temp = &$temp[$key];
}
```

which, thanks **only** to `$temp = &$temp[$key]`, results in:

```
$res = [
  "item1" => [
    "item2" => [
      "itemx" => & null
    ]]]
```

I don't understand why `&temp[$key]` instantiate the association `[$key => null]` and `$temp[$key]` doesn't.

I did some debug and for the first `$key` (*item1*):

1. $a = $temp[$key]:

   - gives *"undefined index" notice*.
   - dumping `$a` returns null.
   - dumping `$temp` returns null.
2. $a = &$temp[$key]:

   - doesn't give *"undefined index" notice*.
   - dumping `$a` returns null.
   - dumping `$temp[$key]` returns null.
   - dumping `$temp` returns:
     `["item1" => & null]`

Which means that `$temp = & $temp[$key]` instantiate also $temp[$key] or equivalently it is preceded by:

```
$temp = &temp[$key]; <=> $temp[$key] = null; $temp = &temp[$key];
```

I would like to understand if that is explained somewhere in php documentation (I searched but I hadn't found anything) or if I'm missing something obviuos.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation. Undefined variables are created when a reference is created:

> **Note**:
>   If you assign, pass, or return an undefined variable by reference, it will get created.
>
> **Example #1 Using references with undefined variables**
>
> ```
> <?php
> function foo(&$var) { }
>
> foo($a); // $a is "created" and assigned to null
>
> $b = array();
> foo($b['b']);
> var_dump(array_key_exists('b', $b)); // bool(true)
>
> $c = new StdClass;
> foo($c->d);
> var_dump(property_exists($c, 'd')); // bool(true)
> ?>
> ```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Comment: It's what I was looking for! Thank you!